# How to use a function with mutable number of arguments in R

Tags: r

I have two `tibbles` with different number of columns. I want to filter `df1` using a value from column `b` and I also want to filter `df2` using a value from column `b` and also column `c`. Is it possible to do this using the same function?

I followed the list(...) procedure, but of course, I got an error since, in the first case there is no x[[2]].

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- tibble(a = c(4,2,3,4),
              b = c(8,6,7,8))

df2 <- tibble(a = c(1,2,3,4),
              b = c(5,6,7,8),
              c = c(1,5,3,7))

df1
#> # A tibble: 4 × 2
#>       a     b
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     4     8
#> 2     2     6
#> 3     3     7
#> 4     4     8
df2
#> # A tibble: 4 × 3
#>       a     b     c
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     5     1
#> 2     2     6     5
#> 3     3     7     3
#> 4     4     8     7

createTable <- function(df, ...) {
  x <- list(...)
  tabl <- df %>%
    filter(b < x[[1]], c < x[[2]])
  return(tabl)
}

tabl1 <- createTable(df1, 8)
#> Error in `filter()`:
#> ! Problem while computing `..2 = c < x[[2]]`.
#> Caused by error in `x[[2]]`:
#> ! subscript out of bounds
tabl2 <- createTable(df2, 7, 5)
Created on 2022-07-27 by the reprex package (v2.0.1)
```

Comment: Do you use multiple arguments for the same column i.e. 'b' or should it always look for 'c' when there are 2 elements?

Comment: Also, would it be better to pass an expression

Comment: No, it should not look for `c` when c does not exist, like in `df1`.

Comment: I meant to say `createTable <- function(df, expr) {
 df %>%
    filter({{expr}})
};

createTable(df1, b < 8); createTable(df2, b < 7 & c < 5)` works for both conditions

Comment: Your current function should also take care of cases where the column 'c' exist, but you pass only a single value.  It may be better with an expression as input

Comment: Can I use the expression with other arguments like function(df, arg1, arg2, expr)?

Comment: Depends on how you are using `arg1` and `arg2` along with expr